# Why is pyInstaller trying to import tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller

My pyInstaller build is trying to install tkinter, which is causing all kinds of problems. I can work around them, but the real question is why is it trying to import tkinter at all? I'm using wx!

Here are my dependancies:

```
qrcode==5.3
PyExecJS==1.1.0
pysftp==0.2.8
six==1.10.0
requests==2.10.0
paramiko==1.15.2
nose==1.3.7
verlib==0.1
jsbeautifier==1.5.4
ecdsa==0.13
wxPython==3.0.3.0b20160914
invoke==1.0.0
polib==1.0.6
macholib==1.11
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
PyInstaller==3.4
mandrill==1.0.57
mock==2.0.0
ndg_httpsclient==0.5.1
pymongo==3.7.2
PyYAML==5.1
```

So, why is it trying to include tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

tkinter is used by pillow. Pillow (in turn) is needed by qrcode.